# What kind of ogg does Android Chrome support?

Tags: ffmpeg, web-audio-api, ogg, vorbis, chrome-for-android

I've found that I can only play some ogg vorbis files in Android Chrome. Most notably, I cannot play the ogg files generated by Mauz Kahn's demo here: https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/ffmpeg/wav-to-ogg.html
I used his demo to create some test ogg files using Windows Chrome and I could play them back while I was using Window's Chrome, but I could not play those same audio files in Android Chrome. I've played other ogg vorbis files in Android chrome so I suspect there is a subtle issue in the [parameters that Khan's demo invokes ffmpeg with](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/blob/5964a4b70681dcd1e5ac58605386b28c7fe49484/ffmpeg/wav-to-ogg.html#L194).

Comment: Ogg is just a container format.  Are you exclusively talking about Ogg Vorbis files?  Or are you using some other codec within Ogg?

Comment: AFAICT it's vorbis given that it appears in the arguments FFMPEG is called with.

Comment: I know Speex is supported with Chrome because I use it with speex.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to play vorbis audio in Android Chrome by using the a web audio container and specifying the codec in the source tag. For more details see https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/issues/159